# php jQuery with .change how can you automatically change the value

Tags: jquery

I have this image and i like to work it out on jQuery now the image have a fixed size, but when I input on the `<input type='text' name='img_logo' value='630px'>`

Like I put for example `530px` the image size should be change also.

Here's my code.

```
<form method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="logo_width" value="632px">
    <p>Format logo: <span id="logo_size">632px</span></p>
</form>
```

the jQuery codes

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="logo_width"]').change(function(e) {
        var chk = $('input[name="logo_width"]').val();
        $('img#img_logo').attr(chk);
    });
});
```

and the image

```
<div class="logo">  
     <img src="images/upload/' . $set_logo_img['filename'] . '"
         width="630px" align="center" id="img_logo" />
     <br /> 
</div>
```

But when i do input some value on the `input='name=logo_width'` nothings change
is my code jQuery wrong?

Comment: Note that change event fires only when you leave the input field. If you would like to update size whenever you enter value you should use "input" event

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to fix some of your jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="logo_width"]').change(function(e) {
        var chk = $('input[name="logo_width"]').val();
        $('img#img_logo').attr("width", chk); // set attribute width value with chk
    });
});
```